# How can I configure Microsoft Teams on iPad so that it does not fit the incoming video(s) to the screen?

Tags: ipad, ms-teams

By default, Microsoft Teams on iPad fits the incoming video(s) so that there is no black empty space, e.g. see the left half:

[image]

Instead, I want the full video, e.g. see left half:

[image]

How can I configure Microsoft Teams on iPad so that  it does not fit the incoming video(s) to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2023-05-18: MS Teams introduced a new feature "fit to frame". Hold on a video to see the context menu, then select "fit to frame":

[image]

To reverse it, select `Fill Frame`:

[image]

---

It seems it's not possible yet to configure Microsoft Teams on iPad so that it does not fit the incoming video(s) to the screen. As Reddit user [jjgage](https://www.reddit.com/user/jjgage) [mentioned](https://www.reddit.com/r/MicrosoftTeams/comments/10npo68/how_can_i_configure_microsoft_teams_on_ipad_so/j6co4c5/):

> just pinch to zoom out on their video feed.

It works but as soon as I stop pinching, the video goes back to the default auto-fit that crops the video.